# onClickListener for custom ListView item with multiple Buttons

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

In my program, I have a Fragment which dynamically adds custom items to a ListView. These items each have 2 Buttons, which are supposed to have a certain functionality (like removing the specific item from the list). I would like to set an OnClickListener for them, calling a function within my Fragment Class.

Simple xml onClick attributes cannot find the function and when I try to add the onClickListener within the onCreateView() method (like with Listeners for static Buttons). But when the fragment is created, a NullPointerException is called, because the referenced Buttons are not part of the Fragment (?).

How can I call a function from my Fragment after pressing a dynamically added Button (or Checkbox)?

Comment: one item in listview with two buttons ? not working click ?

Answer (score 0):

this is easier if you post some code

In my code I have something similar, I have one listview with a Array Adapter, and in some line I have one imageButton with a funtion.

I solve my problem with a class to work on my adapter and in that that I apply the functionaly to the Button.

Main_Class code :

```
ListViewResources listViewResources = new ListViewResources(this, resourcesName);
listView = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(listViewResources);
```

ListViewResouces_Class:

```
public class ListViewResources extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

Activity context;
String[] resourcesName;


public ListViewResources(Activity context, String[] resourcesName) {
    super(context, R.layout.popup_listitem_resources, resourcesName);

    this.context = context;
    this.resourcesName = resourcesName;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_listitem_resources, null, true);

    TextView resourceName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewResourceName);
    ImageView openResource = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOpenResource);

    openResource.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code for happen on Button Click
        }
    });

    resourceName.setText(resourcesName[position]);

    return rowView;
}
```